# Importação do pacote numpy

Tags: python

No Windows 10,usando Python 3.6.0.  Como devo fazer para importar o modulo numpy1.11.2? Já usei o miniconda e o pacote foi carregado mas não obtenho exito no interativo do python Python 3.6.0.
Grato

Comment: O uso/importação é simples: `import numpy as np`, por exemplo. Se você está com algum erro, indique-o. Dizer "não obtenho exito" é insuficiente, e faz a sua pergunta não ser clara. Ah, se não fez ainda, não deixe de fazer o [tour] e ler [ask].

Comment: Coloque na sua pergunta qual erro está aparecendo quando tenta importar o numpy, assim ficará mais fácil de ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser de dois jeitos:

`from numpy import *`

ou

`import numpy`